# Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi 4 Internet/Date Issues

Tags: networking, ethernet, raspberrypi, date

I have installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB model. It's meant to be a media/file server for my parents.

I set everything up on it at my house and it works great.
However, when I hook it up at my parents, it simply will not get on the network. The only real difference between my house and my parents is the network.

I have tried multiple Ethernet cables.
If I ping anything, i get `ping: <hostname>: Temporary failure in name resolution`.
On the router's admin panel, I can see the Pi's MAC address but hostname is blank.
`ip route` comes back empty.
I've tried plugging directly into the router and also through a switch into the router.

The other odd and possibly related thing is that the date on the Pi is always wrong there. When plugged in at my place, it gets the time fine through the network.
When plugged in at my parents, the date is stuck at the last time I had it on the network. I `set-ntp off` and set the date manually and `set-ntp` on again.
`timedatectl`1 reads this after that

```
                <roughly correct time, since I manually set it>
                Time zone: <Correct time zone>
System clock synchronized: no                          
              NTP service: active                       
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

I'm really at a loss at this point. The only difference is my router vs. my parents, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with their router.

Please, does anybody know what else I may try to fix this issue?

Edit:
To answer some comments...

No MAC filtering is enabled, and DHCP is enabled on the router.

The router is from the ISP, Slic Network, and it is a 844G-1.
`sudo dhclient -v` results in `DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0|eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 at interval` for a few minutes, eventually resulting in `No DHCPOFFERS received.`.

I do not see anything glaringly wrong in the log files.

UPDATE:
Since this is not at my home, I am not able to try different things regularly. However, I did recently visit and can provide some new information:

- Other computers besides the Pi are NOT able to connect to the internet or obtain in IP when plugging in to the router. We thought this was workign from the beginning so I did not test this, but we tried a different device into multiple ports on the router and it did not work.
- When plugging in a second router into the first, it was able to obtain an IP and it's admin panel was accessible through this IP on the network. However, plugging the Pi or a PC into the second router yielded the same results as the first and they were unable to obtain an IP.

Comment: Do you see any suspicious log in the output of ```cd /var/log ; sudo grep -ir "dhcp" * 2>/dev/null```? Does ```sudo dhclient``` help? If not , what about [setting a static IP address](https://www.osradar.com/set-a-static-ip-address-ubuntu-20-04/) ?

Comment: What brand router is at your parents'? Some allow a maximum number of connections, has that perhaps been set?

Comment: It is a curious problem. Perhaps the scope of IP addresses available to handout isn't correct/exhausted on the router? What you really need to do is use something like Wireshark to capture the traffic and see exactly what is happening during the TCP handshake as well as the DHCP request/return.

Comment: Also found this interesting thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244061#p1661217

Comment: Does your RP have wifi? can it draw an IP from any other router or maybe your phone if you make it a hot-spot? Can maybe your phone connect to their router's wifi without problem? I know you mentioned wires, I don't know if wifi is in play here? Also did you attempt a static connection like @ParsaMousavi suggested? if you say the router is in default state then IP 192.168.1.251 mask 255.255.255.0 dns 8.8.8.8 should get you on the internet. Also you can try tcpdump -i eth0 and/or tcpdump -i wlan0 and verify youre seeing traffic from ANY devices...

Comment: @Mark Although that thread is interesting and finally solved that problem, but I think it cannot help OP because that was for debian buster.In ubuntu 18.04 vanilla for example there is no service named ```dhcpd.service``` nor in the entire ubuntu repository(I said that based on ```apt-file search```).But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi The reference to that article was to point out that in an edge case experiencing a quite similar problem, there was a forced delay introduced to the DHCP demon by a config file. It was intended to give the OP something else to look for. [Had I believed it to be a solution to the problem I would have posted it as an answer not a comment.]

Comment: What does `ifconfig` say? And I know this isn't the solution, but I'd try Ubuntu 16 to make sure it's really a network issue.

Comment: @WU-TANG Wifi works for other devices from this router, and so does wired LAN. Wifi worked on the Pi with Rasbian installed, have not tried from Ubuntu since we want LAN only as this will be a server.
@Mark As stated above, Ubuntu does not have dhcpcd installed, although this was a good idea for things to look for, I did not find anything. @hextech, `ifconfig` is not installed by default. I would have to install `net-tools` but without internet at my parents, that is difficult. `ip addr` does not give an IPv4 address.

Comment: The things suggested aren't meant to be "workarounds", they are to establish more facts. Without much to go on, the functioning or not-functioning things suggested narrow down the unknown. We're trying to see all behaviors, mostly new additions... You've already described what already works with the existing devices, we kinda need to know what else does not work.... not to mention if you tried wifi or a static IP and that worked, then you would have had a connection to install the other suggested tools to continue troubleshooting the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just got mine to work by changing the ethernet to NOT optional in the netplan. This is a context diff of the simple change that got the Ethernet to work for me on my RSP4...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu: diff -c /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml ./50-cloud-init.yaml
*** /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml     2020-11-09 21:43:47.392519398 +0000
--- ./50-cloud-init.yaml        2020-04-01 17:23:49.227999995 +0000
***************
*** 7,11 ****
      ethernets:
          eth0:
              dhcp4: true
!             optional: false
      version: 2
--- 7,11 ----
      ethernets:
          eth0:
              dhcp4: true
!             optional: true
      version: 2
ubuntu@ubuntu:
```

Before I did this, the network would not come up.

Chris Shaker

Comment: I was having problems getting it to format the context diff correctly. The blockquotes worked.


Just change 'optional: true' to 'optional: false' in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

Answer (score 0):

The time is unlikely related, since the rpi has no RTC, it needs to get time from the network at each boot.

It probably isn't a firewall issue if DHCP is failing, since isc-dhcp-client uses raw sockets, bypassing firewall rules, unless, of course, there are some rules listed with `iptables -vnL -t raw`. Are there multiple instances of dhclient running? Before manually running `dhclient -v`, try running `killall dhclient` first. This might give you some more debug output.

If the router sees the Pi's MAC address, does it also list an IP address?

With all that said, I bet it's just a typo, probably somewhere in your DNS config, or netplan/networkd. To check, ping your router's IP address, not hostname.